# Group a button with a link

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/49/). As you see, the button makes everything fall apart.

My attempt was:

```
button {
    left: 50%;
    position: inherit;
    top: 50%;
}
```

but that did not help much! How should I do it?

[image]

Here is the HTML too:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone"> 
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-grid-solo" id="slots">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <ol data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                        <li data-role="list-divider">Europe</li>
                        <li class="ui-btn-icon-left"><a href="#">Kahn</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-btn-icon-left"><a href="#">Ferdinand</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-btn-icon-left"><a href="#">Nesta</a></li>
                    </ol>

                    <button class="depth" type="button">&#10004;</button>

                    <a href="#popupNested" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" data-transition="slidedown">Info</a>
                    <div data-role="popup" id="popupNested" data-theme="none">
                        <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" style="margin:0;">
                            <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
                                <h2>Log in</h2>
                                <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
                                    <li><a href="#" data-rel="dialog">To sign up,<br>contact Samaras!</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- /collapsible -->                 
                        </div><!-- /collapsible set -->
                    </div><!-- /popup -->

                    <ol data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                        <li data-role="list-divider">Europe</li>
                        <li class="ui-btn-icon-left"><a href="#">Kahn</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-btn-icon-left"><a href="#">Ferdinand</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-btn-icon-left"><a href="#">Nesta</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D I can copy paste all the code from the jsFiddle in the question. Would that improve me question? :)

Comment: Just enough to reproduce the issue although a *Stack Snippet* would be preferred

Comment: Updated @Paulie_D, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply add

```
position: absolute;
left: calc(50% - 40px);
top: 35px;
```

to your CSS, right here:

```
button.depth {
    /* Here */
}
```

Here is your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7gxpqn0/53/) with these changes

To avoid using Absolute positioning, you could solve this wrapping your buttons inside a div with `display: inline-block`

```
<div class="btn-container">
    <!-- Your buttons -->
</div>

.btn-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7gxpqn0/54/).

Comment: I would like the button to be placed above the link, so that the lists would have the button AND the link in the space between them. Is that possible please?

Comment: Sure, just add:  `top: 35px;` , I'll edit the answer to accomplish this aswell

Comment: In my real application, the button goes in the textbox (see the image in my question), because of the `absolute`. Note that even if I adjust this, what about mobiles? It is not good enough. Or maybe we could have media queries? If you make the screen of the result smaller in the fiddle, the button will overwrite the first list, instead of going underneath the list (that's the real problem).

Comment: It will always be horizontally centered, but vertically might need a little bit more atention. Because its absolutely positioned it will overlap with other elements, anywyas. I'll give you a `display: inline-block` solution.

Comment: @gsamaras Check the answer now please

Comment: That's perfect. However, in my real code the button goes all the way to left. I will look into this, thanks!

Comment: I could reproduce my problem here (but could not fix it), if you have a moment please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/56/